# Vimscript function to select block then sort

Tags: vim

I'm learning Vimscript and I'm trying to select a block of text and sort it via a function. Here's what I got right now:

```
function! SortFirstBlock()
    call setpos(".", [0, 1, 1, 0])
    execute "normal! vip:sort<cr>"
endfunction
```

How I read this is to go to the first position in the buffer via `setpos`, then with `execute`, run `vip` which visually selects a block of text, then `:sort` to sort that block.

My cursor goes to the first position, but doesn't highlight the block and doesn't sort. What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’ve upvoted glts’ answer but I thought I’d offer an alternative solution.
Instead of selecting before sorting, you can simply sort from the position you just moved to (the start of the file) to the line just before the end of the current paragraph:

```
function! SortFirstBlock()
    call setpos(".", [0, 1, 1, 0])
    ,'}-1sort
endfunction
```

Nothing before the comma means the start of the range is the current line.
The `'}` is a predefined mark which indicates the end of the paragraph. The
`-1` moves the end-point of the range to be sorted back by one line so that
the blank line at the end of the paragraph isn’t included in the sort. This
range covers the same lines that would be included with a `vip` in Normal
mode.

Answer (score 3):

Almost there, all that's missing is a backslash before `<CR>`:

```
function! SortFirstBlock() abort
  call cursor(1, 1)
  execute "normal! vip:sort\<CR>"
endfunction
```

`<>` tokens must be inside a double-quoted string and escaped. The documentation for all such special tokens is at [`:h expr-string`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#expr-string).

---

Two unrelated suggestions, code review style:

- You can use `cursor()` as a shorthand for `setpos(".", ...)`.
- Always use `abort` to make a function stop as soon as it encounters an error. If you don't use `abort` Vim will try to continue executing even after an error and you'll get a long and confusing stacktrace.

Answer (score 3):

What's wrong with your function:

- `setpos()` is too verbose, `cursor()` is simpler,
- `execute` is not necessary because you don't concatenate anything,
- you should separate macros and ex commands:

  ```
  normal! vip
  sort
  normal! <Esc>
  ```
- but visual mode is totally unnecessary here anyway.

You should use `:sort` over the desired range:

```
function! SortFirstBlock()
    1,/^$/-sort
endfunction
```

Well, I would simply use `:1,/^$/-sort<CR>` and don't bother with a function, actually… but your example may be part of a larger whole.

Comment: `1,'}-sort` does not seem to work. It will sort everything from line 1 to the end of the current paragraph, not the end of the paragraph starting from line 1.

Comment: Great answer. I'd modify the one-line command to `1,/^\s*$/-sort` for a better simulation of the range that would be selected by `vip` in Normal mode.