# How to select first paragraph of file without moving cursor in Vimscript?

Tags: vim

With the answers from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33576268/vimscript-function-to-select-block-then-sort), I've put toegther a little function to help me insert language pragmas into a source code file:

```
function! HaskellInsertLanguagePragma() abort
    let here = getpos(".")
    let prag = input("GHC pragma: ")
    call append(0, "{-# LANGUAGE " . prag . " #-}")
    call setpos(".", [0, 1, 1, 0])
    ,'}-sort
    ,'}-Tabularize /#-}$/
    call setpos(".", here)
endfunction
```

Basically, it asks you for a keyword, then inserts it, along with the boilerplate into the first line of the file, sorts, it, and lines up the closing delimiter using the [Tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular) plugin. Awesome.

The problem with the function is that, because a line is inserted, the `setpos` at the end puts the cursor at the line previous to when it started now. The obvious solution is to `setpos` with the line number incremented by one, but I wonder whether either of the following two solutions might be better:

1. Set a mark at the beginning of the function and go to that mark at the end. If so, how to set and move to marks within Vimscript?
2. Don't move the cursor at all, and do the `,'}-sort` and `,'}-Tabular` using explicit ranges. But how do I specify the range "first paragrpah of the file"?

To me it seems that being able to select the first paragraph of the file is the better approach. Appreciate any help in figuring out how to do this.

Comment: I've edited my answer to your first question. "first paragraph of the buffer" is `1,/^$/-`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Vimscript, I normally set mark before, and move back to after.

```
function! MyFunction()
    " Save our location.
    normal! mz

    ...

    " Move back to our original location.
    normal! `z
endfunction
```

Answer (score 0):

[@Andy Ray](https://stackoverflow.com/users/743464/andy-ray) answered your first question very nicely. About the second one, unfortunately, even using explicit ranges, it seems that `sort` function using a range changes the position of the cursor. How to specify a paragraph with a range? You can use

```
1;'}-sort
1;'}-Tabularize /#-}$/
```

When separated with `;` the cursor position will be set to that line
before interpreting the next line specifier, so you do not need to move cursor position to the first line (check [`:h :,`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#:,)). Or you can use a pattern

```
1;/^$/-sort
1;/^$/-Tabularize /#-}$/
```

`^$` means blank line, which usually ends paragraph. The `/` after `pattern` is required for separation.

- [`:h [range]`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#cmdline-ranges)
- [`:h sort`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#sorting)